# Run a command that uses pipes in terminal on Mac using Java

Tags: java, macos, shell, terminal

I have a command to run on Terminal OSX:

```
cat File1 | ./huawei2text.pl > ~/File2.txt && cat ~/File2.txt| tr "," "\n"  > ~/Output.txt
```

How can I run this command using only java?

I tried this code:

```
String whatToRun = "cat File1 | ./File.pl > ~/File2.txt && cat ~/File2.txt| tr "," "\n"  > ~/Output.txt";
   try
   {
     Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
     Process proc = rt.exec(whatToRun);
     int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
     System.out.println("Process exitValue:" + exitVal);
   } catch (Throwable t)
     {
       t.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Updated

Answer and solution:

```
String whatToRun = "cat File1 | ./File.pl > File2.txt "
            + "&& cat File2.txt| tr \",\" \"\n\"  > Output.txt";
String[] shellcmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", whatToRun};

try {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = rt.exec(shellcmd);
    int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Process exitValue:" + exitVal);
    }
catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now It works. Thank you!

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Program is working, but there is not any actions. Only output: "Process exitValue:1"

Comment: The exit value indicates that what you pass to `exec` is not working; it is likely a command not found error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipes would be interpreted by the *shell*.  Ask your shell to execute the command instead:

```
String[] shellcmd = {
  "/bin/sh",
  "-c",
  whatToRun
};

Process proc = rt.exec(shellcmd);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java API allows you to start *one* subprocess, by naming an executable to run. What you have there is a whole mini-script banged together into a one-liner. Only a shell can interpret such things, so your string should start with something like

```
/bin/sh -c '... your command ...'
```

Note the single quotes, they are important.